# Avoid Constant file from decompilation

Tags: java

I am new in development. I need to protect my application constant file from decompilation. How can I do this? Is there anyway, please help me out.

Comment: [java protect against decompilation](https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&ei=9ISwWpzeCIql8AXhyaho&q=java+protect+against+decompilation&oq=java+protect+agains+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i13k1j0i13i30k1l2.5866.9012.0.10877.15.12.0.1.1.0.265.1477.0j3j4.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..8.7.1214...0j0i10k1j0i22i30k1.0.xqaiM2XZlj4)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do **obfuscate**. If you have created your Constant.java as interface then avoid it the way you created. Create the simple class and try to keep encrypted values specially which are highly confidential. I hope it will help you.

Comment: And since you can decompile the code, how hard would it be to determine the decryption algorithm and/or keys? "Download the keys" - Wireshark